# Object Detection : Face Mask Detection From TensorFlow notebook on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api

link to the notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord.ipynb#scrollTo=HQzaEQuJiW_d

i get this error : NotFoundError: /content/Tensorflow-Object-Detection/efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32/export/pipeline.config; No such file or directory

Comment: Please, add the relevant part of your code to your question. Can you show what you have tried? It would be better if you added the code you are trying to write so others could answer your question better. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Following these guidelines makes your question easier to understand and more likely to be answered.

Comment: Hi @MaiconMauricio the link you have provided does not contain any code related to object_detection. Could you please provide the provide the proper link ? Thank You!

Comment: Hi, @TFer. I think you tagged the wrong person :) My main complaint was that he didn't have the relavant part of the code on the question because his notebook might get deleted at any time